# NestJS stuck on File change detected. Starting incremental compilation

Tags: nestjs

I'm having endpoint which is receiving file and store it in folder. However at the moment when add `destination` - where file to be stored and hit the endpoint server stuck and i receive this message: `[17:54:47] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...`

This is how to controller looks like:

```
@ApiResponse({ type: CreateNFTRespDto })
  @ApiBody({ type: CreateNFTReqDto })
  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
    dest: './images'
  }))
  createNFT(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Body() data: CreateNFTReqDto,
  ) {
    return this._nftService.createNFT(file, data);
  }
```

Any idea why is not able to compile, I think i had similar issue with the firebase and the reason there was the package was very big or something like this, could be the same with the Multer or so?

Comment: maybe you're watching for changes in some dir that is being changed? try to use another destination path (far from your source code)

Comment: its documented now here https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#file-change-detected-loops-endlessly

Comment: @AmanGupta love u, man, THAT'S THE ANSWER

Answer (score 1):

just add the file location folder in tsconfig.build.json as i did with 'media'

```
"exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts", "**/media"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have downgrade the typescript version as following in package.json file

```
"typescript": "4.8.3"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload.

I have tried everything but only that worked.